# What are the advantages of decoding a JSON file as an array or an object?

Tags: php, json

Recently, I've started forraying into PHP and I've started using JSON files. The JSON_decode() function has the option to decode the file as an associative array or an object. I'm not to clear what the real difference is between using one or the other, can someone explain?

Comment: object notation `$object->prop`, assoc array, `$array['prop']`.

Comment: I think its more  a matter of preference, I don't know if there is any significant advantages to either way.

Comment: It depends on the requirement. And everyones has their own choice to implement. You can choose whatever want.

Comment: My preference is to not use JSON at all, but use PHP array files.  Which does have some significant performance benefits but also some security concerns.

Comment: what are you using JSON for here?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix That may not be an option if you're getting data from an API. You're stuck with the format they return, and usually the choices are JSON and XML.

Comment: @Barmar - I agree with you, I based that comment on this `started using JSON files` which is an assumption on my part granted.  But PHP array is my preferred config file, doesn't get any faster then that.

Comment: What is a PHP array file? Do you mean `serialize()`?

Comment: No, its a file like this `return ['stuff' => 'foo'];` then `$conf = include 'config.php'`  Literally a PHP array in a file, saving it is not for novices though for security reasons, but you can do `file_put_contents('config.php',  '<?php return '.var_export($array, true).';')';`  Just I wouldn't recommend saving user input in there.  Although I think var_export dose a fair bit of escaping, I'm just cautious about that.

Comment: @rtfm I'm getting a JSON file from a webhook and what I'm getting from the file is subscriber information.

Answer (score 0):

Before you json_decode, the json data is a string that you cannot access the properties of.

The difference between object or array is just the way you access values:

```
$value = $array['key'];
$value = $object->key;
```